# Error migrating from cannon.js to cannon-es

Tags: cannon.js

I have a world with cannon.js physics working fine. When I try to migrate to cannon-es I get an error in the `step()` function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: bodies[i].integrate is not a function
```

The `step()` function is:

```
this.physicsWorld.step(1 / 60, this.experience.time.delta, 3)
```

And the docs for the `step()` function: https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/classes/world.html#step

I can't find anything wrong. What does that error means?

[image: console error bodies[i].integrate is not a function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to import cannon-es instead cannonjs in one file, so I was using a mix of two libraries.